# How to fix, assignments must be the first block of code on a line?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpcs, phpcodesniffer

I'm developing WordPress plugin and stuck with code sniffer warnings. How do I fix the below warning message?

> [Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found] Assignments must be the first block of code on a line

The above error/ warning is highlighting for the below code.

```
$testimonial_gravatar_image = $out = $before = $after = '';
```

How do I define those empty variables? If I skip or remove then the error displays undefined variable etc.

`$testimonial_gravatar_image` is inside the while loop and `$out` for generating output.

Comment: what is your php version.

Comment: The sniffer rule is named "DisallowMultipleAssignments". It doesn't accept multiple chained assignments. Initialize each variable with the empty string in a separate statement.

Comment: Isn't there any other logics to do or avoid or suppress the warning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$testimonial_gravatar_image = '';
$out = '';
$before = '';
$after = '';
```

Comment: Please accompany your answer with an explanation